# Using tortoiseSVN and SubWCRev, but WCREV&, WCREV- WCREV+ operations not working

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We're trying to get the revision number and do some basic operations with it.  The retrieval of the revision number works great, but the operations do not:

We run it as follows:

```
SubWCRev.exe . buildNumTemplate.txt buildNum.txt
```

In the buildNumTemplate.txt we have the following

```
#WORKS
Revision:   $WCREV$
Modified:   $WCMODS?Yes:No$
Built_On:   $WCNOW$

#DOESN'T WORK
Revision_Minus_100: $WCREV-100$
Revision_Plus_100: $WCREV+100$
Revision_Append: $WCREV&test$
```

After running the above command, we get the following which shows the problem:

```
#WORKS
Revision:   35592
Modified:   Yes
Built_On:   2013/07/10 11:58:45

#DOESN'T WORK
Revision_Minus_100: $WCREV-100$
Revision_Plus_100: $WCREV+100$
Revision_Append: $WCREV&test$
```

Is there something odd in the way we are running SubWCRev such that it is not doing the operations correctly?  If we can't get this to work, we'll probably do some operations with the ant build script using the math operations there to get the desired result.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but running 1.7.7 build 22907 exactly as specified in the manual I get the same results you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SubWCRev knows and processes only predefined set of keywords, where `$WCREV$` exist, but `$WCREV<ANYTHING>$` - doesn't. Thus your "variables" aren't expanded and calculated.

**Edit**

Re-checked documentation and my SubWCRev. Because URL is http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev-example.html (contain RELEASE) it's supposed to be correct only for the release (latest public version). Release for today is

`SubWCRev 1.8.0, Build 24401`

and for this version template from manual working without any problem. It looks like you used the documentation for the wrong version which caused the confusion.

For my last-used repo-URL

```
// Test file for SubWCRev

char *Revision      = "1244";
char *Revision16    = "220";
char *Revisionp100  = "1344";
char *Revisionm100  = "1144";
char *Modified      = "Not modified";
char *Unversioned   = "no unversioned items";
char *Date          = "2013/04/01 08:30:36";
char *CustDate      = "Mon, 01 April 2013";
char *DateUTC       = "2013/04/01 02:30:36";
char *CustDateUTC   = "Mon, 01 April 2013";
char *TimeNow       = "2013/07/11 11:06:28";
char *TimeNowUTC    = "2013/07/11 05:06:28";
char *RevRange      = "1263";
char *Mixed         = "Not mixed";
char *ExtAllFixed   = "All externals fixed";
char *IsTagged      = "Not tagged";
char *URL           = "https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/customlocations-greylink/trunk/city";
char *isInSVN       = "versioned";
char *needslck      = "FALSE";
char *islocked      = "not locked";
char *lockdateutc   = "1970/01/01 00:00:00";
char *lockdate      = "1970/01/01 06:00:00";
char *lockcustutc   = "Thu, 01 January 1970";
char *lockcust      = "Thu, 01 January 1970";
char *lockown       = "";
char *lockcmt       = "";

#if 0
#error Source is modified
#endif

// End of file
```

`WCREV&` keyword in your sample even in 1.8 **must** be used in proper way: read keyword description carefully in doc:

> Replaced with the highest commit revision in the working copy, ANDed with the value after the & char. For example: $WCREV&0xFFFF$

I.e right part of expression must be A NUMBER, not a custom text-string for URL-like resulted text (see Revision16 variable and original number in the sample above)

Comment: `$WCREV+100$` is an example [given in the SubWCRev documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev-example.html) and it's not working for either of us.

Comment: Exactly - I don't really see this mentioned anywhere else on the web so either it is functionality that isn't really used anywhere or it broke with a recent build.  I will have to see if there is a developers forum for tortoiseSVN and see if they can take a look.

Comment: @alroc - it's doc for **RELESE**, not for ancient versions. For 1.7 read correct branch of docs - for 1.7

Comment: @LazyBadger It *is* possible to correct people without verbally attacking them. If you're going to yell at people for reading the wrong version of the documentation, the least you can do is [point them at the correct version](http://www.cs.siue.edu/~wwhite/CS325/CourseNotes/TortoiseSVN_1_7.pdf) (which is rather difficult to download via Sourcefroge, I might add)

Comment: @alroc - I **have not problems** finding old manual and downloading from SF (used http://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/tortoisesvn/1.7.13/Documentation/TortoiseSVN-1.7.13-en.pdf)

Comment: @LazyBadger I've now tried at least 3 mirrors, 2 different versions, on two different internet connections, and have not succeeded in downloading it (and the link you've given is blocked by my corporate Barracuda web filter) - which is why I posted the link to the file that *does* work for me. But keep up the personal attacks, they *really* make you look good here.

Comment: @LazyBadger - Correct answer, but you need to take a step back and re-examine why you're helping people out.  Thanks for the answer though!